# How to draw continuous line graph in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm very new to VB.NET. I'm trying to draw continuous line graph based on certain time intervals using the graph UI control. I'm able to draw the graph the first time and getting unhandled exception on second time. Please refer to my code below,

```
Dim s As New Series

    s.Name = "aline"

    'Change to a line graph.
    s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line

    For index As Integer = 1 To 10
        s.Points.AddXY("1990", 27)
        s.Points.AddXY("1991", 15)
        s.Points.AddXY("1992", index)
    Next
    Chart1.Series.Add(s)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    s.Points.AddXY("1993", 27)
    s.Points.AddXY("1994", 15)
    s.Points.AddXY("1995", 10)
    Chart1.Series.Add(s)'Here im getting exception
```

But on second time if I try to update the values using `Chart1.Series.Add(s)`, I'm getting "A chart element with the name 'aline' already exists in the 'SeriesCollection'" error. Please guide how to update the values continuously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to do anything to get the chart to update - just remove the second `Chart1.Series.Add(s)`.

In some cases, you may need to force an update, in which case you would use the [Chart.DataBind method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd468034%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

From the Remarks section of the DataBind method documentation:

> In cases where a data source is set to a chart and no other data operations are required, the DataBind method does not have to be explicitly called. In these cases, the Chart itself will data bind to the data source prior to being rendered.

The action of this is easier to see if you add a button to the form to add some values: when you click the button, you see the chart adjust its x-axis and add the new points.

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

Public Class Form1
    Dim s As New Series

    Sub DoChart()

        s.Name = "aline"

        'Change to a line graph.
        s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line

        For index As Integer = 1 To 10
            s.Points.AddXY("1990", 27)
            s.Points.AddXY("1991", 15)
            s.Points.AddXY("1992", index)
        Next
        Chart1.Series.Add(s)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        s.Points.AddXY("1993", 27)
        s.Points.AddXY("1994", 15)
        s.Points.AddXY("1995", 10)
        'Chart1.DataBind()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DoChart()

    End Sub

End Class
```